# Any Ideas on how to fix this error?

Tags: c++, unix, compiler-errors

I keep getting the an exception when I attempt to compile my C++ code on a Unix server, but those lines just have:

```
#ifndef WEIGHTED_GRAPH_H
#endif
```

and the error is:

```
In file included from Weighted_graph_tester.h:17,
                     from Weighted_graph_driver.cpp:18:
    Weighted_graph.h:1: error: stray â\357â in program
    Weighted_graph.h:1: error: stray â\273â in program
    Weighted_graph.h:1: error: stray â\277â in program
    Weighted_graph.h:1: error: stray â#â in program
    In file included from Weighted_graph_tester.h:17,
                     from Weighted_graph_driver.cpp:18:
    Weighted_graph.h:172:2: error: #endif without #if
    Weighted_graph.h:1: error: âifndefâ does not name a type
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You probably have some weird characters in your source code.  Try viewing it in a hex-viewer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's telling you that you have the following bytes in your file:

```
Oct: 357 273 277
Hex: EF  BB  BF
```

These are the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in UTF-8 encoded files. Obviously your compiler does not support UTF-8 source files with the byte order mark at the beginning of them. In fact, it doesn't even make sense to have the byte order mark in a UTF-8 file since any single unit is only a byte in size. You should make sure that you save the file without it.

From the Unicode Standard:

> Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, but may  be encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other encoding forms that use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8 signature.

Comment: Yup That was it, I moved the code over to a new file and it fixed the issues. Thanks :) Will give you the check as soon as it will let me

Comment: A UTF-8 BOM does identify a file as UTF-8. But that's not a good enough reason to use it. It breaks too many useful characteristics of UTF-8 files, making it difficult to concatenate files or extract portions of them.